# Remove elements with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have an html string and i want to remove it...

```
$html = '<h2 class="post-title entry-title">Some Title</h2>';

$removeit = preg_replace('#<h2 class="post-title entry-title">(.*?)</h2>#', '', $html );
```

Why i can't remove it? in other case if i will use the code bellow i can remove a div like

```
$html = '<div style="width:300px; height:120px; background-color:#000;">Some Title</div>';

$removeit = preg_replace('#<div style="width:300px; height:120px; background-color:#000;">(.*?)</div>#', '', $html );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend, try use strip_tags function. you can see how to use in php docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php